# Document or jQuery $ not found in puppeteer using Deno

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, puppeteer, deno

I am using [deno](https://deno.land/) (alternative for node.js) for web scraping and using puppeteer module of it. This is the module I am using
https://deno.land/x/puppeteer@5.5.1

So, my code is

```
import puppeteer from "https://deno.land/x/puppeteer@5.5.1/mod.ts";
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto("https://www.amazon.com", {waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'});
await page.addScriptTag({url: 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js'});
const result = await page.evaluateHandle(() => {
    console.log(document)
    let ele = $('.nav-search-dropdown')
    var data = {
        categories: []
    }
return data;
})
await browser.close();
```

Here `document` keyword is undefined and `$` is also not available. When I try to run this file using deno, it give me following errors:

```
Cannot find name 'document'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the `lib` compiler option to include 'dom'.
```

And error for $ is `undefined`

**Note: When I try puppeteer with node in same way, it works. But I need to use deno for showing a demo of web scraping.**

Comment: Its evaluate, not evaluate handle.

Comment: @John I used evaluate first, it didn't work for document keyword or jquery. So, puppeteer docs included evaluate handle as well, So I tried using this one too.

Comment: I tried with their tsconfig (https://github.com/lucacasonato/deno-puppeteer/blob/main/fixtures/dom-tsconfig.json) and got rid of the `document` error, but unfortunately now got the error `error: TS2339 [ERROR]: Property 'getIterator' does not exist on type 'ReadableStream<Uint8Array>'.
  for await (const chunk of response.body!.getIterator()) {`

Comment: did you try what i suggested in my comment above? What's the result?